# Formatting JSON with jq to create scaleable variables

Tags: json, bash, graphql, jq

I'm working on a project to solve a small use case and learn in the process (First time coding)

But currently stuck at an impasse, as I'm not sure on how the best way would be to move forward.

```
name: Archive old kanban cards
 
on:
  schedule: 
    - cron: 0 0 * * MON
  workflow_dispatch:
 
jobs:
  archive-old-kanban-cards:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, internal]
    steps:
    
    
      - name: Query project for archivable cards
        env:
          GH_ENTERPRISE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GRAPHQL_TOKEN }}
          GH_HOST: github.com
          PROJECT_ID: 12345
 
          
        run: |
          GQL_QUERY='query ArchivableCards($endCursor: String, $projectid: ID!) {
            node(id: $projectid) {
              ... on ProjectV2 {
                items(first: 100, after: $endCursor) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      fieldValueByName(name: "Status") {
                        ... on ProjectV2ItemFieldSingleSelectValue {
                          optionId, item {
                            id, updatedAt
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  pageInfo {
                    endCursor, hasNextPage
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }'
            
          gh api graphql --paginate --raw-field "projectid=$PROJECT_ID" --raw-field "query=$GQL_QUERY" --jq '.data.node.items.edges[].node.fieldValueByName' |
            jq --slurp '[.[] |
              select(.optionId == "98236657"
                and (.item.updatedAt |
                  fromdate) <= now - 60*60*24*60).item.id]'
```

This gives me this output:

```
[
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00ODc=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00MDE=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00MDc=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00NzE=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00MTk=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00MjA=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00NzI=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00NzM=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00NzQ=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00NzU=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00NzY=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00Nzc=",
  "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00Nzk="
]
```

I want to use the JSON output and take these IDs and insert them into a GraphQL mutation:

```
mutation(
  $projectid: ID!
){
  mutation1: archiveProjectV2Item(
    input: {projectId: $projectid, itemId: "MDEzOlByb2plY3RWMkl0ZW00ODc="}) {
    clientMutationId
  }
  mutation[Increasing numbers]: archiveProjectV2Item(
    input: {projectId: $projectid, itemId: (JSON OBJECT)}) {
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

It needs to be scalable so the "mutation#" increases so the inputs are unique, this needs to be done due to limitations in GitHubs GraphQL Schema. (To my knowledge)

An input can't be reused and thus needs to be named, in my case "mutation#:"

In the "archiveProjectV2Item(input: {projectId: $projectid, itemId: )" only one ID can be inserted, thus creating a need for this workaround.

My current thought is to just take the whole mutation part and insert the ID's into it with the needed GraphQL syntax around it. But this can't really be the correct way to do it.

I would be grateful for your input!

Comment: I've gone ahead with the only way I could think of that was the easiest to implement.
Which is using jq and adding strings before and after the id like this https://jqplay.org/s/zU9e5T0Yj14

The plan is to use the whole raw output as a variable and input it in the mutation code.